# Modify inputType:number|phone Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-inputtype

Is it possible to modify inputType:Phone in android studio somehow? 
It would be handy to get the # * keys to other icons and submit. The only way to submit now is to press back button on the phone to get out of the input-keypad.

Comment: "Is it possible to modify inputType:Phone in android studio somehow?" -- no. "The only way to submit now is to press back button on the phone to get out of the input-keypad" -- [use `android:imeOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#attr_android:imeOptions) and related attributes to control the IME action button (typically in the lower-right corner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these two lines in your EditText xml

```
<EditText 
 android:imeOptions="actionGo"
 android:inputType="number"/>
//the action button of keyboard will change to go button
```

then you can set on click of that button in java

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Here you can perform actions");   //like btn.performClick();
        return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
});
```